# How can I know the displayed text in the UILabelView?

Tags: iphone, text, uilabel

How can I know the displayed text in the UILabelView? I have a large text and I am going to have 3 uilabels that represent 3 columns of an iPad App like NYTimes one. When I put the large text in the first column (UILabelView) I need to know how much of the text is displayed there..

If U suggest another solution please let me know. 
Charly

Comment: What is a `UILabelView`?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is a way to measure text.  The iPhone SDK documents a way to find out how big a body of text is, but not how much text fits in a given space.  You can use the former to do the latter iteratively.

Look in UIStringDrawing.h for the following method:

```
- (CGSize)sizeWithFont:(UIFont *)font forWidth:(CGFloat)width lineBreakMode:(UILineBreakMode)lineBreakMode;
```

Use this method to do a (preferably binary) search on different length substrings of your string until you find a substring that fits a particular height.  You have now figured out how much text the first UILabel can display.  Repeat for each column.

You could also use CTTypesetter in CoreText, but that is 3.2 forward.